# How to append new, unique values in gsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a table of values whereby on column needs to show unique, newly added rows from another range in the sheet, but *keep the order in which they appeared*, so another column in the same row could be updated by someone.

Currently, I am using the gsheet UNIQUE formula, but that does not preserve order. Therefore, when another user updates the data, new values appear & the order changes, messing up the other columns of data.

Example:

```
Invoice #   Amount     Approval Status  Payment Status
GN-2018-02  $0.00      Waiting  
GN-2018-03  $0.00      Waiting  
JW-2018-16  $1,372.06  Waiting  
JW-2018-17  $0.00      Waiting  
KR-2018-10  $350.00    Waiting
```

So when someone chooses an approval status, then a new invoice # is added, the invoice # order changes, changing the approval status. Again, I'd like to preserve the order & append new values to the invoice # column, instead of it updating the order every time new data is added.

I need it structured this way because this sheet has access by admin/management, and there are individual sheets per sub-contractor that they fill out, so they only have access to their sheets.

If there's another way to accomplish this same thing, please give me some ideas. Thanks in advance!

Sample data here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PIAomb6-Ln1CGZ2ekfuyoRLwXwmhuP9akGnlakqfdQg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: filter by count?

Comment: what do you `unique` on? the whole row? changing this to a `filter` as suggested on the previous comment might work. but it is tough to write the formula without seeing your unique formula.

Comment: The unique formula is simply =UNIQUE(A:A) - like that. But when a new value is added, the order of the rows is not preserved. What would filter by count do? Example? Answer? Thanks!

Comment: I added a sample data spreadsheet. There are a couple columns. You can see that with the way the data is grouped (importing data from multiple sheets), when a new Invoice # is added, they order by order they APPEAR, not by order they were ADDED. I'd like to APPEND NEW VALUES to the end of the list. Any ideas?